# How to efficiently populate extra properties in the Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm migrating *Gradle* build scripts from *Groovy* to *Kotlin DSL* and one of the things which is not really documented is how to populate [extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

In *Groovy*, I can write:

```
ext {
    comp = 'node_exporter'
    compVersion = '0.16.0'
    compProject = 'prometheus'
    arch = 'linux-amd64'
    tarball = "v${compVersion}/${comp}-${compVersion}.${arch}.tar.gz"
    downloadSrc = "https://github.com/${compProject}/${comp}/releases/download/${tarball}"
    unzipDir = "${comp}-${compVersion}.${arch}"
}
```

I figured out that in the *Kotlin DSL*, I can achive the same functionality with:

```
val comp by extra { "filebeat" }
val compVersion by extra { "6.4.0" }
val arch by extra { "linux-x86_64" }
val tarball by extra { "${comp}-${compVersion}-${arch}.tar.gz" }
val downloadSrc by extra { "https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/${comp}/${tarball}" }
val unzipDir by extra { "${comp}-${compVersion}-${arch}" }
```

which looks pretty repetitive.

Implementation of [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) in *Kotlin* is a little bit complex, but at the end, it holds just plain old `Map<String, Object>`.

So, my question: **is it possible to populate `extra` object with multiple properties more easily, than just repeating `val myProp by extra { "myValue"}`?**

Comment: Maybe this question will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589153/how-are-gradle-extra-properties-set-in-the-kotlin-dsl

Comment: @Opal I read the question you are mentioning, but although it tackles very similar topic, it doesn't ask, nor answer my issue. However, there is alternative solution in _Kotlin DSL_ (`mapOf` -> `forEach` -> `extra.set()`), but IMHO it obfuscates the purpose (it is less readable).

Comment: Maybe something like this?

    `extra.properties.putAll(pairs = listOf(
     "comp" to "filebeat",
     "compVersion" to "6.4.0"
    ))`

Comment: or just a series of `extra["key"] = "value"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According the current (`5.2.1`) documentation:

> All enhanced objects in Gradle’s domain model can hold extra user-defined properties. This includes, but is not limited to, projects, tasks, and source sets.
>
> Extra properties can be added, read and set via the owning object’s `extra` property. Alternatively, they can be addressed via Kotlin delegated properties using `by extra`.

Here is an example of using extra properties on the `Project` and `Task` objects:

```kotlin
val kotlinVersion by extra { "1.3.21" }
val kotlinDslVersion by extra("1.1.3")
extra["isKotlinDsl"] = true

tasks.register("printExtProps") {
    extra["kotlinPositive"] = true

    doLast {
        // Extra properties defined on the Project object
        println("Kotlin version: $kotlinVersion")
        println("Kotlin DSL version: $kotlinDslVersion")
        println("Is Kotlin DSL: ${project.extra["isKotlinDsl"]}")
        // Extra properties defined on the Task object
        // this means the current Task
        println("Kotlin positive: ${this.extra["kotlinPositive"]}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use delegation, just write `extra.set("propertyName", "propertyValue")`. You can do this with an `apply` block if you want:

```
extra.apply {
    set("propertyName", "propertyValue")
    set("propertyName2", "propertyValue2")
}
```